# Camel route "to" specific websocket endpoint

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have some camel routes with mina sockets and jetty websockets. I am able to broadcast a message to all the clients connected to the websocket but how do i send a message to a specific endpoint. How do i maintain a list of all connected clients with a client id as reference so i can route to a specific client. Is that possible? Will i be able to mention a dynamic client in the to URI?

Or maybe i am thinking about this wrong and i need to create topics on active mq and have the clients subscribe to it. That would mean that i create a topic for every websocket client? and route the message to the right topic.

Am i atleast on the right track here, any examples you can point out? Google was not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you take depends on how sensitive the client information is. The downside of a single topic with selectors is that anyone can subscribe to the topic without a selector and see all the information for everyone - not usually something that you want to do.

A better scheme is to use a message distribution mechanism (set of Camel routes) that act as an intermediary between the websocket clients and the system producing the messages. This mechanism is responsible for distributing messages from a single destination to client-specitic destinations. I have worked on a couple of banking web front-ends that used a similar scheme.

In order for this to work you first generate for each user a distinct token/UUID; this is presented to the user when the session is established (usually through some sort of profile query/message). 
It's essential that the UUID can be worked out as a hash of the clientId rather than being stored in a DB, as it will be used all the time and you want to make sure this is worked out quickly.

The user then uses that information to connect to specific topics that use that UUID as a suffix. For example two users subscribing to an `orderConfirmation` topic would each subscribe to their own version of that topic:

```
clientA -> orderConfirmation.71jqsd87162iuhw78162wd7168
clientB -> orderConfirmation.76232hdwe7r23j92irjh291e0d
```

To keep track of "presence", your clients would need to periodically send a heartbeat message containing their clientId to a well-known topic that your distribution mechanism listens on. Clients should not be able to subscribe to this topic for reads (see [ActiveMQ Security](http://activemq.apache.org/security)). The message distribution mechanism needs to keep in memory a data structure that contains the clientId and the time a heartbeat was last seen.

When a message is received by the distribution mechanism, it checks whether the clientID for which it received the message has a "live/present" session, determines the UUID for the client, and broadcasts the message on the appropriate topic.

Over time this will create a large number of topics on your broker that you don't want hanging around when the user has gone away. You can configure ActiveMQ to [delete these if they have been inactive for some time](http://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html).

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not want to create separate endpoint for each client.
Topic and a subscription with selector is an elegant way to resolve it. 
I would say the best one.

You need single topic, which every client would subscribe to with the selector looking like `where clientId in ('${myClientId}', 'EVERYONE')`. Now when you want to publish a message to specific client, you set a property clientId to the id of this client. If you want to broadcast, you set it to 'EVERYONE'

I hope I understand the problem right...